# Azure create "Container Apps Environment" Networking, can't be added to existing vnet

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

I can't add "Container Apps Environment" to existing vnet ? the subnets are not loading
and if i click on new subnet i can see all the existing subnets.

can new "Container Apps Environment" be added to an existing vnet ?

### [image]

### [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add a container app to an existing VNET.

Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/networking?tabs=azure-cli#subnet), There are few things you need:

- For workload profile environment, you need a subnet with at least `/27` size and the subnet must be delegated to `Microsoft.App/environments`.
- For consumption only environment, you need a subnet with at least `/23` size.

Looking at your screenshots, the existing subnets are too small and the Vnet itself is too small `/24`.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas. I had to allocate address pace and then create a subnet 
"10.1.0.0/23" that gave me 507 ips

Comment: if you use workload profile, you only need /27 subnet and it also support consumption plan